# How To Stop Javascript Menu Underline from going to Dropdown Box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I created a menu underline in javascript. How do I stop the underline from going on the dropdown menu links? The problem is when I move the mouse out the menu and you still see the line.

Please let me know what is the best way to fix this. Thank you so much.

https://codepen.io/rubenjr005/pen/ExjQdjw?fbclid=IwAR1iXxZro17fFRKXmWKmi4N6sj0d_mRL6g4-MeVNaHip4IvUYM4YtCGJDPc

[image]

[image]

```js
(function() {

  const target = document.querySelector(".target");
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".mynav a");
  const colors = ["deepskyblue", "orange", "firebrick", "gold", "magenta", "black", "darkblue"];

  function mouseenterFunc() {
    if (!this.parentNode.classList.contains("active")) {
      for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].parentNode.classList.contains("active")) {
          links[i].parentNode.classList.remove("active");
        }
        links[i].style.opacity = "0.25";
      }

      this.parentNode.classList.add("active");
      this.style.opacity = "1";

      const width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      const height = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      const left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.pageXOffset;
      const top = this.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
      const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

      target.style.width = `${width}px`;
      target.style.height = `${height}px`;
      target.style.left = `${left}px`;
      target.style.top = `${top}px`;
      target.style.borderColor = color;
      target.style.transform = "none";
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => e.preventDefault());
    links[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", mouseenterFunc);
  }

  function resizeFunc() {
    const active = document.querySelector(" .mynav li.active");

    if (active) {
      const left = active.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.pageXOffset;
      const top = active.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;

      target.style.left = `${left}px`;
      target.style.top = `${top}px`;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeFunc);

})();


/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,900&display=swap');


/* 
YELLOW - #f7c51e
GREY - #363636
background white - #f6f6f6

*/



* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}


.color-overlay-container {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.color-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}


.btn-black{
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.btn-yellow{
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    color:  white;
    background: #f7c51e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}


body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


p {
    margin: .5rem 0;
}

/* Utility Classes */

/* Grid Container */


.grid-container {
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
}

.grid-container-2 {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1rem;
}


/* Grid Container - END */


.container {
    max-width: 1404px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}


.text-yellow {
    color: #f7c51e;
}

.bg-yellow {
    background: #f7c51e;
    color: black;
}

.bg-grey {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: black;
}


.l-heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.m-heading {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.lead {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 0.75rem 0;
}



/* Padding */

.py-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
}

.py-2 {
    padding: 2rem 0;
}

.py-3 {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}


/* All Around Padding */

.p-1 {
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.p-2 {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.p-3 {
    padding: 3rem;
}


/* Utility Classes - END */



/* ================  HOME PAGE ==================== */


/* HEADER */



.site-header {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.site-header .header-container {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

/* BLACK BAR */

.site-header .header-container .header-container_wrap {
    padding: 30px 5px;
    /* background: red; */
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items {
    display: flex;

}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .contact-info {
    display: flex;

}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .quality-logo {
    margin-right: 3rem;
    line-height: 5px;
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .quality-logo p {
    font-size: 14px;
}


#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}


#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item .facebook-like {
    text-align: center;
}



#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .item .fas  {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f7c51e;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
}


#masthead .header-container .header-container_wrap .items .contact-info .item .fas  {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f7c51e;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #363636;
}

/* ========================== Bottom White Header Menu  - START ================ */


/* Menu Underline */


.mynav a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 15px;
  }
  
  .target {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .mynav a,
  .target {
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  }



/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;

  }


  #myTopnav .items {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
  }
  

  #myTopnav .items .item .mynav ul{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
  }
  

  #myTopnav .items .item .mynav ul li{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
  }
  

  #myTopnav .items .item .mynav ul li:nth-child(4){
      margin-left: .5rem;
      /* background-color: red; */
  }
  
  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .topnav a {
    /* float: left;
    display: block; */
    color: rgb(94,94,94);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  
  /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

/*     
    .active {
     color: black;
    font-weight: 600; 
    color: #363636;
   }  */
  

  /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  

  /* ============================ DROP DOWN MENU =============================== */
  /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
    /* float: left; */
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(94,94,94);
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7c51e;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgb(94,94,94);
  }
  
  /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.mynav   .dropdown-content a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  /* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
  .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    /* background-color: red; */
    color: black;
    

  }
  
  /* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    /* background-color: red; */
    color: black;
    
  }

  
  /* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    z-index: 101;
  }
  
  
  /* SEARCH ICONS */

  #myTopnav .items .item .fa-search{
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      color: #363636;
  }




/* ========================== Bottom White Header Menu - END ================ */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-REHJTs1r2ErKBuJB0fCK99gCYsVjwxHrSU0N7I1zl9vZbggVJXRMsv/sLlOAGb4M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CSS STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="css/mobile.css">


    <!-- Swiper Header Slider -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/swiper.min.css"> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css"> -->


    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body id="home">


    <!-- Header Container -->

    <!-- Navbar-Black -->
    <div id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav class="header-container">

            <!-- Top Black Header Bar -->
            <div class="header-container_wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="quality-logo">
                            <img            src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="quality-logo">
                            <p>Offering Quality work at a fair price to the Central Texas area.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-info">
                            <div class="item">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                                <div class="contact-block__value-wrap">
                                    <p> Call Today</p>
                                    <p><strong>(972)-555-5555</strong></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
                                <div class="contact-block__value-wrap">
                                    <p>Mon-Fri:<strong> 7am to 7pm</strong></p>
                                    <p>Sat & Sun: 9am-4pm</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                                <p>Serving Central Texas</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="facebook-like">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                                    <p>LIKE US</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- ======================== Bottom White header START ======================-->


            <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="item">
                            <nav class="mynav">

                                <!-- <a href="#home" class="active">Menu Click Here</a> -->
                                <!-- Hamburger -->
                                <ul>
                                    <div class="hamburger">
                                        <!-- <p class="active">Menu Click Here</p> -->
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><p>Menu Click Here </p>  &#9776;</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <li><a href="#home">About</a>
                                    
                                    <!-- DROPDOWN MENU -->
                                    
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="dropdown">
                                                <button class="dropbtn">
                                                
                                                    <a href="">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                                    
                                                </button>
                                                
                                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                                    <a href="#">Brush Mulching & Land Clearing</a>
                                                    <a href="#">Mapping & Measurement</a>
                                                    <a href="#">Erosion Mitigation / Driveways / Roads</a>
                                                    <a href="#">Landscaping & Drainage Management</a>
                                                    <a href="#">Foundation & Pads</a>
                                                    <a href="#">General Dirt Work & Tank Pond Trenching</a>
                                                    <a href="#">Demolition & Clean Up</a>
                                                    <a href="#">Septic Installation</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                  
                                    <!-- DROPDOWN MENU END -->
                                    
                                    <li><a href="#home">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#home">Video Example</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#home">Contacts</a></li>
                                    <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a> -->
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                            

                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="target"></span>

            <!-- ======================== Bottom White header END ======================-->
            
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- HEADER CONTAINER END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another event listener that will check if the mouse leaves the whole navigation.
Then you can remove the inline style, thus reseting the target element.

```
document.querySelector(".mynav").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  target.removeAttribute("style");
})
```

Comment: It Worked! Thank you so much!